# How can I access DatePicker value in JavaFX for SELECT MySQL Query?

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx

I'm building a very simple hotel booking program with JDBC. I have 3 tables

1. Guests(GuestID,LastName,FirstName,Email,PhoneNumber)
2. Rooms(RoomNumber,Type,Rate)
3. Reservation(RoomNumber, CheckInDate, CheckOutDate).

If I choose a date and press "Search" button, the tableview should list all the available rooms. However, mine shows nothing.

[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K76eH.png)

[Empty TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPW6.png)

The following code is what I did for DataSource class.

```
public static final String QUERY_VACANCY = "SELECT r.* FROM " + TABLE_ROOMS + " r WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM " + TABLE_RESERVATION + " re WHERE " +
        "re." + COLUMN_ROOM + "=" + "r." + COLUMN_ROOM + " AND " + "((?>=re." + COLUMN_CHECKIN + " AND ?<re." + COLUMN_CHECKOUT
        + ") OR " + "(?<re." + COLUMN_CHECKOUT + " AND ?>=re." + COLUMN_CHECKIN + ")))";


private PreparedStatement queryVacancy;
private Connection connection;

public boolean open() {
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, "mememem", "somethingsomething123");
        queryVacancy = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY_VACANCY);

        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("CANNOT Connect to the DB: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}



 public List<Rooms> showSearchResult(Date date) {
    try {
        queryVacancy.setDate(1, date);
        queryVacancy.setDate(2, date);
        queryVacancy.setDate(3, date);
        queryVacancy.setDate(4, date);
        ResultSet resultSet = queryVacancy.executeQuery();

        List<Rooms> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Rooms room = new Rooms();
            room.setRoomNumber(resultSet.getInt(COLUMN_ROOM));
            room.setType(resultSet.getString(COLUMN_TYPE));
            room.setRate(resultSet.getInt(COLUMN_RATE));

            rooms.add(room);
        }
        return rooms;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("QUERY FAILED: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

For the controller, I created the following code.

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Rooms> roomsTableView;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker checkindatepicker;

    public LocalDate getCheckindatepicker(){
        return checkindatepicker.getValue();
    }

    public void listSearchedRooms(){
        Task<ObservableList<Rooms>> task = new GetSearchedRooms();
        roomsTableView.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());

         new Thread(task).start();
    }
}



class GetSearchedRooms extends Task{

private Controller controller;
    @Override
    protected ObservableList<Rooms> call() throws Exception {

        controller = new Controller();

        Date date = Date.valueOf(controller.getCheckindatepicker());

        System.out.println(date.toString());

        return FXCollections.observableArrayList
                (DataSource.getInstance().showSearchResult(date));
    }

}
```

Here is my FXml Code.

```
<center>
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="40">
        <children>

            <HBox alignment="CENTER">
                <Label text="Date: "></Label>
                <DatePicker fx:id="checkindatepicker"></DatePicker>
            </HBox>
            <Button text="Search" onAction="#listSearchedRooms"></Button>
            <Button text="Reserve" onAction="#showReserve"></Button>
            <Button fx:id="checkReservation" text="Check Reservation" onAction="#showReservation"></Button>
        </children>
    </VBox>
</center>
```

What I understand is that, a String value should replace the "?" parts of PreparedStatement. That's why I did

```
        String date = (java.sql.Date.valueOf(checkindatepicker.getValue())).toString();
```

in call() method

What should I do?

**EDIT:** The annotated field should be in Controller class. Due to so, I added private variable checkindatepicker in Controller class. Also, to retrieve its value, I created a method getCheckindatepicker(). Then, I created an instance of Controller class in GetSearchedRooms class. Using getCheckindatepicker() method, I would get the value of the chosen date and convert it to java.sql.Date.
However, it's still not working.

There must be nothing wrong with the PreparedStatement nor showSearchResult() method, because with the following code, the tableview shows the available rooms on August 31st.

```
class GetSearchedRooms extends Task{
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Rooms> call() throws Exception {

            String str = "2017-08-31";
            Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(str);

            System.out.println(date.toString());

            return FXCollections.observableArrayList
                    (DataSource.getInstance().showSearchResult(date));
        }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't your `call()` method throw a null pointer exception? I don't see any way `checkindatepicker` could be initialized (it's not initialized in code, and it's not defined in the controller, so the `@FXML` is redundant). Can you use an `onFailed` handler with the task, or wrap the code in `call()` in a try-catch block to verify?

Comment: @James_D If I understand correctly, you are wondering where I defined checkindatepicker. I linked in FXml. I will add my FXml atm.

Comment: But `@FXML`-annotated fields are only initialized in the controller.  Your `GetSearchedRooms` instance isn't the controller. Have you checked if it is null?

Comment: @James_D This will be the stupidest thing you've ever heard. I thought  FXML annotated field can be initialized anywhere in "Controller.java". Which means, GetSearchedRoom class is in "Controller.java". I must be fully wrong. Now, I am just panicking...

Comment: @James_D Would you please let me know how to solve it?

Comment: You should set a date using `setDate`, and if you also have a time component, then `setTimestamp`, you shouldn't convert to string. Also: that part of your question technically has nothing to do with JavaFX, you really need to separate concerns, that will also make it easier to see if the problem is with your query or with your UI code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, as you suggested, I changed queryVacancy.setString to queryVacancy.setDate in showSearchResult(Date date) method. I alsco modified call() method in GetSearchedRooms class in Controller.Java. It's still not working

Comment: Now I think the problem is FXML annotated field as James mentioned. If I set String str="2017-08-31";  Date date=Date.valueOf(str); in call() method in GetSearchedRooms class, it works. Have to do more research!!

Comment: @James_D I editied my program and my checkindatepicker is still null. What should I do?

Comment: Declare it in the controller and pass it (or better, its value) to the `GetSearchedRooms` instance when you create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
class GetSearchedRooms extends Task{

    private final Date date ;

    GetSearchRooms(Date date) {
        this.date = date ;
    }

    @Override
    protected ObservableList<Rooms> call() throws Exception {




        return FXCollections.observableArrayList
                (DataSource.getInstance().showSearchResult(date));
    }

}
```

And then back in the controller replace

```
Task<ObservableList<Rooms>> task = new GetSearchedRooms();
```

with

```
Task<ObservableList<Rooms>> task = 
    new GetSearchedRooms(Date.valueOf(checkindatepicker.getValue()));
```

In both cases the `Date` class is `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: I just want to say I think it would be better to add NullPointerException.

Comment: public GetSearchedRooms(Date date) throws NullPointerException{     this.date = date;}   and try-catch block in listSearchedRooms method

Comment: @ChrisLEE it's never a good idea to catch a null pointer exception. You can always write code to avoid it if a value might be null.